# Get information abuot arduino ethernet card

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am using an Arduino-uno connected to a local network via an Ethernet Shield and I am trying to get the configuration information of its ethernet card (for example: IP address, subnet mask, gateway, DNS). Is there a function that allows me to get this data and save it in some variables?

Comment: it is documented. no problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Ethernet class to set and query information like IP address, subnet mask and alike.

For example, Ethernet.localIP() will return, well the local IP address.

More information [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/ethernet/).